Updating a nested object in json and saving it back to original
I have big json, where i am renaming a nested object .module.home.[].list member from object_old to object_new and then deleting the object_old key.
cat out.json
{
    ...
    {
    "objecta": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2
    },
    "objectb": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2
    },
    "object_old": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2
    }
    }
    ...
}

jq ".module.home.[].list | .object_new = .object_old | del(.object_old)" out.json
{
  "objecta": {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2
  },
  "objectb": {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2
  },
  "object_new": {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2
  }
}

Now, while i was able to update .module.home.[].list, i only have the updated sub object in the output. How can i get the entire json back with the updated object_new, so i can save it back to out.json

This question is similar to: jq rename nested json key and place under same key. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
